# What is the difference between "short int" and "short" in c?

Tags: c, gcc, int, embedded-linux, short

what is the difference between declaring the variables as short int and short?
In gcc compiler the short  occupies 2 bytes(checked with sizeof(short)),and short int is also giving the 2bytes of size.Is both are same are different?In which case these declarations will helpful?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`short` is short for `short int`, they are equivalent in any C compiler.

The same for `long int` vs `long`, `long long int` vs `long long`.

Comment: Same for long and long int.

Comment: Does anyone know the history behind this? Why it was included at all?

Answer (score 4):

`short`, `short int`, `signed short int`, and `signed short` are all same data-types.

So `sizeof(short) == sizeof(short int)`

The same goes for `long`

Comment: You forget `auto signed short int` :P

Comment: @AlterMann: `auto` is a storage class specifier, like `static`, `extern`, `register`, etc.  It doesn't specify a type.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I mean `auto signed short int x;` =  `short x;`, but it's a joke ...